# How i can use differents html template for the same typescript file?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to use differents html template for the same typescript file, based in an expression in my constructor. this is possible?

I need something like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
     <app-teste1 *ngIf="teste == '1'>
     <app-teste2 *ngIf="teste == '2'>
</div>
```

and in the **constructor:**

```
this.teste = 1
```

So the first component must be renderized (app-teste1).

But my component have much properties, there's other way to make this without pass various input/output properties?

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think that is available in angular now (`angular 8.0.0-beta.13`).**

You can manipulate and render DOM tree in many different way but loading different template (`.html`) file is not possible in angular as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from a base class and use a different template. Something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-teste1',
  template: `<div>this is app-teste1</div>`
})
export class TestOneComponent {
    // ...
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-teste2',
  template: `<div>this is app-teste2</div>`
})
export class TestTwoComponent extends TestOneComponent {
    // ...
}
```